# Using github3.py, how do I increase GitHub's rate limit using only client_id and client_secret?

Tags: python, github-api, github3.py

I want to increase GitHub's rate limit by passing `client_id` and `client_secret` with the request. I don't want to use user/pass or OAuth authentication. I just want to make a request equivalent to:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases?client_id={id}&client_secret={secret}
```

Does github3.py provide a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`github3.py` does allow you to use your `client_id` and `client_secret` parameters:

```
import github3


gh = github3.GitHub()
gh.set_client_id(client_id, client_secret)
```

That said, by default, your ratelimit will still only be 5000 requests per hour (not including the Search API) so if you need more than that, you should contact GitHub's support team to increase it for you.